# In Rails, are all the method inside of View helper methods? Any method inside View is not helper method? (except other object's method invocation)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is it true that inside of View, either we are showing static content, or else, all the method calls in View are helpers...  are there methods that belong to ActionView?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there a re a few methods that belong directly to ActionView (or more precisely to ActionView::Base) most notably the `render` method. However you do not need to call it with the `ActionView::Base` prefix.

See http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Base.

Comment: hm... can render be implemented as a helper method too?  (coz it looks like one too)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what exactly do you mean by that.